# Importing 3D Scene into VR Project in Unity does not work

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, importerror, virtual-reality

I recently modeled a space station in Unity (in a 3D template, using assets from the unity asset store). My friends had set up a VR template project into which I wanted to drag the space station. Everything worked so far.

However, the textures were suddenly pink, and I couldn't solve that either, no matter which "Pink Textures" tutorial I looked at. I then wildly adjusted some files, settings etc. until the textures were suddenly there. Nevertheless, I could only start the project with the Valve Index once, and after I had finished the game, I could only start it again after I had completely restarted the computer. I know that the error must lie somewhere in the rendering pipeline, but unfortunately nothing helped.

Unfortunately, I have not found an article that refers to a similar problem, so I am asking this question here. Really appreciate any helpful answers that come my way.

I tried the following things in summary:

- Rendering Pipeline Convert => Goal: Space station works in VR with all Textures, some Textures changed, but they were looking really ugly.
- Material Changes per Prefab, did not work
- wild changes in several files => Goal: Space station works in VR with all Textures, Textures were loading, but VR only worked once...